# Is there any library available for balancing imbalanced text dataset?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, preprocessing, text

I have a text dataset similar to newsgroup dataset, the problem with the dataset is that it is highly imbalanced. So is there any readily built library that will do upsampling or downsampling with a function call?

[image: Imbalanced dataset]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import ADASYN, SMOTE, RandomOverSampler
from imblearn.under_sampling import NearMiss, RandomUnderSampler

ros = RandomOverSampler(random_state=777)
X_ROS, y_ROS = ros.fit_sample(testing_tfidf, testing_target)

smt = SMOTE(random_state=777, k_neighbors=1)
rus = RandomUnderSampler(random_state=777)
```

Good article for [reference](https://towardsdatascience.com/yet-another-twitter-sentiment-analysis-part-1-tackling-class-imbalance-4d7a7f717d44)

Comment: This is good for Python, is there an equivalent in R?

Comment: https://topepo.github.io/caret/subsampling-for-class-imbalances.html
A good reference

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good blog for handling this in R.
[Class imbalance](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/03/imbalanced-data-classification/)